# forward mapping with ado.net entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

i'm experimenting the entity framework lately,

i wonder is it possible to model entities in designer view from scratch then let the framework handle the schema creation, foreign keys and such automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity Framework team calls this "[model first](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/09/10/model-first.aspx)." It is not a feature of the currently shipping Entity Framework, but it will be in .NET 4.0. You can see a demonstration if you watch [the PDC video](http://mschnlnine.vo.llnwd.net/d1/pdc08/WMV-HQ/TL20.wmv).

Comment: thank you :)

downloading the video now. Article doesn't mention about what will it do when it comes to updating schema as the entities grow though...